# Is this implementation SQL-92 conformant?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[Tony Andrews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18747/tony-andrews) in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461985/better-way-to-structure-a-pl-sql-if-then-statement) gave an example of:

```
IF p_c_courtesies_cd 
   || p_c_language_cd 
   || v_c_name 
   || v_c_firstname 
   || v_c_function 
   || p_c_phone 
   || p_c_mobile p_c_fax 
   || v_c_email is not null
THEN
     -- Do something
END IF;
```

as a clever (if not a tad obscure) alternative to the Oracle COALESCE function. Sure enough, it works, if any argument is not null, the IF test is true.  My question: Is Oracle's implementation of the above concatenation operation SQL-92 conforming? Shouldn't an expression involving a NULL evaluate to NULL? If you don't think so, then why should the expression 1 + NULL evaluate to NULL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Oracle's treatment of nulls is idiosyncratic, different from everyone else's, and inconsistent with the ANSI standards.  In Oracle's defence however, it probably settled on and was committed to this treatment long before there was an ANSI standard to be consistent with!

It all starts from the fact that Oracle stores strings with a character count followed by the string data.  A NULL is represented by a character count of zero with no following string data - which is exactly the same as an empty string ('').  Oracle simply doesn't have a way to distinguish them.

This leads to some quirky behaviour, such as this concatenation case.  Oracle also has a function LENGTH to return the length of a string, but this has been defined in an opposite manner, so that LENGTH('') returns NULL not zero.  So:

```
LENGTH('abc') + LENGTH('') IS NULL

LENGTH('abc' || '') = 3
```

which seems to me to violate basic mathematical principles.

Of course, Oracle developers become so used to this that many of us can't even see anything wrong or odd about it - some will in fact argue that the rest of the world is wrong and that an empty string and a NULL **are** the same thing!

Answer (score 2):

@Nezroy: Thanks for the link. As I read the standard, however, I believe it states that Oracle's implementation is in fact, incorrect. Section 6.13, General Rules, item 2a:

```
     2) If <concatenation> is specified, then let S1 and S2 be the re-
        sult of the <character value expression> and <character factor>,
        respectively.

        Case:

        a) If either S1 or S2 is the null value, then the result of the
          <concatenation> is the null value.
```

Comment: I initially thought you were asking if the COALESCE implementation was to standard. However, I agree, their CONCATENATION implementation is NOT to standard if it's returning non-NULL for that.

Comment: Yes, my question was not crystal clear. My apologies. At least *I* knew what I meant ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Well COALESCE is explicitly defined by the SQL-92 standard to return the first non-NULL value in the list; so by definition, the Oracle implementation of that is behaving correctly.

EDIT: The [SQL-92 spec](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt); search for COALESCE to see its definition.

That said, there's nothing specific about NULL that states any operation involving NULL must be NULL. The more exact restriction is that NULL is neither false nor 0 nor equal to another NULL (e.g. NULL == NULL is false, because one NULL is not equal to another NULL). That doesn't mean, however, that there can't still be logically consistent ways of working with NULL that don't always return NULL.

EDIT: So NULL + 1 is NULL in the same way that NaN + 1 is still NaN; it's effectively an undefined operation.

Comment: +1 for the link. However, the standard, as I read it, explicitly states the result of concatenating a null value with anything should be a null.

Comment: @DCookie: ah, I thought you were asking if the COALESCE implementation was to standard. However, I agree, their CONCATENATION implementation is NOT to standard if it's returning non-NULL for that.

Comment: Sorry for not spelling it out, I guess I assumed from the example I gave that I was referring to the concatenation operation :-(

Comment: Nah it probably made sense anyway, I'm sure I just skimmed over it too quickly :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the portion of the [SQL-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) spec highlighted by DCookie and the behavior of other DBs, I'd say Oracle is not behaving to standard with their concatenation operator.

Oracle (from tuinstoel's answer):

```
SQL>  select 'something'||null from dual;

'SOMETHIN
---------
something
```

MSSQL:

```
SELECT 'something'+NULL;

NULL
```

PostgreSQL:

```
postgres=# \pset null '(null)'
Null display is "(null)".
postgres=# select 'something'||null as output;
 output
--------
 (null)
(1 row)
```

MySQL:

```
mysql> select concat('something',NULL) as output;
+--------+
| output |
+--------+
| NULL   |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL>  select 'something'||null from dual;

'SOMETHIN
---------
something
```

string concatenation with a null doesn't result in a null. I think this is normal behaviour, I'm used to it. Don't know what else to say.

Comment: Just because Oracle implemented it that way doesn't make it correct.

Comment: Something is correct when it works as explained in the manuals.

Comment: As an example, Oracle's equating the empty string to NULL is not seen as correct by many.

Comment: I'm asking if it conforms to the SQL standard. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Whether or not it conforms to the SQL standard I don't know.

Comment: I'll add that PostgreSQL behaves to standard: "SELECT 'something'||NULL;" returns NULL.

Comment: And MSSQL behaves to standard too, even though they use a "string concatenation" operator specifically: "SELECT 'something'+NULL;" returns NULL.